# Person Name Detection using SpaCy in English Lang. Looking for Answer

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I am using Spacy and trying to detect names in the text. For example, text = 'Keras is a good package. Adam Smith uses a car of black colour. I hope Katrina is doing well in her job.'

The answer should like this: Adam Smith and Katrina.

Can anyone recommend

Comment: What have you attempted so far? And have you had a look at the [docs](https://spacy.io/usage/processing-pipelines) for pipelines?

Comment: I had to face a similar task recently and the other answers are right: SpaCy's NER is a good starting point. If you are interested here are a couple of repositories that may help you with the next steps:  https://github.com/philipperemy/name-dataset https://github.com/leoli51/Names-Oracle

Answer (score 7):

spacy has an label_ called person.  you have several options for the model: small, medium or large.  large uses more resources to run

```py
def find_persons(text):
    # Create Doc object
    doc2 = nlp(text)

    # Identify the persons
    persons = [ent.text for ent in doc2.ents if ent.label_ == 'PERSON']

    # Return persons
    return persons
```

Try nltk to find the Nouns and then pattern match the nouns for valid names:

```py
tokenized_sent = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)
tagged_sent = nltk.pos_tag(tokenized_sent)
```

```
nouns
pronouns
adjectives
verbs

NNP - proper noun singular
PRP - proper noun
VB - verb
DT - determinant

NNP - proper noun singular
PRP - proper noun
VB - verb
DT - determinant
```

Comment: It fails on this example: Hi Mori, thank you for your response. Please get back to us if you have any other issues. Stay safe. - Syed Azeem

Answer (score 6):

This is a typical Named Entity Recognition problem. Spacy has a pre-trained model to enable this, which should be accurate to detect person names.

Take a look at [this code sample.](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#section-named-entities)

According to Spacy's [annotation scheme,](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#entity-type) names are marked as `PERSON`.

Comment: Thanks, Pradip. I suppose NLTK can also solve the purpose. I found a solution.
I will post it soon.